# Какая будет скорость в прокси-сервере если...?

Tags: сервер, сеть, прокси

Если купить 1 серверный или резидентский прокси-сервер. Скорость 100мбит/с (Реальная скорость = ~40мбит/с). И подключить его на 5 пользователей(в браузерах). (Эти 5 человек пользуются разными WiFi сетями)

1. Что будет со скоростью, когда все 5 пользователей будут онлайн и что-то делать в браузерах: Эти 40мбит/с будут у каждого пользователя или эти 40 поделяться между 5ью пользователями (если да, то как) ?
2. Пропускная способность  прокси-сервера уже 1гбит/с. Но у каждого пользователя провайдер поддерживает максимум только 100мбит/с. Если она делится, то как это будет происходить в данном случае: 100 делится на 5 или 1000 делится на 5 и ещё имеется остаток и возможность подключить больше людей?
3. Если пользователи одного прокси находятся в трех странах: Россия, Украина и Казахстан. То для какой страны покупать прокси чтобы среднее значение пинга всех пользователей было меньше?

Решение купить несколько прокси не предлагать - не подходит никак

Заранее большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Заранее узнать нельзя, единственный вариант - взять и померять

Answer (score 0):

1. "Скорость" поделится на 5 участников.
2. Также на всех + остаток.
3. Тут надо смотреть не на страну, а на город, который будет относительно равноудалён от остальных городов других стран. Это при условии, что количество задействованных промежуточных точек между ними будет примерно одинаково, ну и использовуемые средства связи, а также средняя нагрузка. И т.д и т.п. В общем, как уже можно догадаться, эти вещи придётся расчитывать опытным путём.

Отдельно стоит упомянуть про "что-то делать в обозревателях". Можно смотреть передачи, отвечать на вопросы или играть в сети. Всё это требует разной пропускной способности из-за различия в данных, которые задействованы в обмене: одним важна своевременность и не очень важна 100%-я надёжность (например, звук), другим, наоборот, скорость не важна, важна надёжность и т.п. Всё это можно настраивать на промежуточных точках, распределяющих потоки (распределителях). О том, какие настройки будут присуствовать на выбранном устройстве нам неизвестно. Заранее предугадать сложно. Здесь так же придётся вычислять опытным путём.